# Simple Injector Fallback Registration

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I read in the documentation that it's possible to create fallback registrations for unhandled types but I can't seem to find that page any longer. In any case, my question is quite simple assuming I understand fallback registration.

I would like to setup the container to instantiate a `NullCommandHandler<T> : ICommandHandler<T>` type anytime it is unable to locate a registration for a `ICommandHandler<T>` service type. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy, you just use `RegisterOpenGeneric`. This method uses unregistered type resolution, which means it only gets picked up when there's no registration. So with your command handlers, it would look like this:

```
// Register all implementations of ICommandHandler<T>
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

container.RegisterOpenGeneric(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(NullCommandHandler<>),
    Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

[Here is the documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#registration-of-open-generic-types) that you were searching for.

Comment: Thank you for that documentation, I must have missed it the second time around. Does your code function the same as: container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(ReadWriteRepository<>),
    c => !c.Handled); ?

Comment: You can use the `!c.Handled` predicate to use fallback on fallback behavior, which is something that Simple Injector prevents by default, because in most cases having overlapping registrations is a configuration error.